# Obter elemento do click (this) em metodo

Tags: javascript, mvc, classes, método

Estou refatorando uma SPA utilizando na pratica o MVC com classes e etc...

Fiz um método que é chamado quando clico em um elemento `<i>` e gostaria de obter esse elemento para posteriormente deletar um parente dele (uma `<tr>` dois níveis acima).

Estou chamando esse evento no HTML com o attr `onclick="CalculaController.removeLinha()"`

Porém se eu peço pra pegar o `this` ele me retorna a classe controller e não o elemento clicado, fiz alguns testes com evento do tipo `.on('click', function(){return this});` funciona mas não fica ficou 100% esta com alguns erros...

Comment: Poste seu codigo para ajudarmos...

Comment: Resolvido! no attr eu estava chamando o metodo com o this, mas no metodo eu coloquei como parametro o this tbm, e o this dentro da classe sempre é a classe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter seu elemento na função você pode o enviar como um parâmetro pra mesma.
Ex:

```
<i onclick="FuncaoTeste(this);">Teste</i>

var FuncaoTeste = function(element)
{
    console.log(element);
}
```

Caso tenha interesse, dê uma olhada melhor no funcionamento do [this](https://tableless.com.br/javascript-entendendo-o-this/).

Comment: Meu problema foi que coloquei como parâmetro o this no metodo.. era só mudar para element, obrigado!